# Drop down with multiple locations, that should display day and hours open accordingly

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form class="branch-time-selection"><select>
<option selected="selected" data-branch-item="0" value="locationOne">location One</option>
<option data-branch-item="1" value="locationTwo">location Two</option>
<option data-branch-item="2" value="locationThree">location Three</option>
<option data-branch-item="3" value="locationFour">location Four</option>
<option data-branch-item="4" value="locationFive">location Five</option>
</select>
</form>
```

I don't know how to start this, location 1,2, & 3 have these hours: Mon-Thurs 9am-9pm Fri 9am-6pm Sat 9am-5pm Sun 12pm-5pm

Location 4 has these hours: Tues-Thurs 10am-8pm Fri-Sat 10am-4pm Sun-Mon Closed

Location 5: Mon 9am-2pm tues 12-5pm weds 2pm-7pm thurs 12pm-5pm Fri-Sun Closed

Depending on the current day of the week and which location is selected from the drop down I want to display those hours. For example, if today was Weds and I select location 5, 2pm-7pm should display. Please see my full fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/r1ox8a0c/

Comment: Where should the text "2pm-7pm" be displayed? Under the dropdown?

Comment: just right above, in the fiddle you can see where it displays now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hopefully my code can help you in some way, have a nice day!

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="hour"></div>
<form class="branch-time-selection">
<select id="sample" onchange="printHour(this.value)">
<option data-branch-item="1" value="locationOne">location One</option>
<option data-branch-item="5" value="locationFive">location Five</option>
</select>
</form>

<script>
// will return 0 as sunday, 1 as monday and go on
var today = (new Date()).getDay();

// uncomment this code bellow to mock today as tuesday
// var today = 2

// set branch open hour
var branch = {
  "locationOne" : [
    "12pm-5pm", //sunday
    "9am-9pm",
    "9am-9pm",
    "9am-9pm",
    "9am-9pm",
    "9am-6pm",
    "9am-5pm" //saturday
  ],
  "locationFive" : [
    "closed", //sunday
    "9am-2pm",
    "12-5pm",
    "2pm-7pm",
    "12pm-5pm",
    "closed",
    "closed" //saturday
  ]
}
 
function printHour(val) {
  if(val){
    document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML =  branch[val][today]
  }
}

// print on load
printHour(document.getElementById("sample").value)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks!! but is there a way to do this with JS instead??

Comment: your welcome, by "JS" do you mean not using "jquery"? btw technically "jquery" is "JS" library. so everything written in "jquery" is actually "JS"..

Comment: yea I meant in javascript

Comment: how can I have location one be the default that is displayed until another selection is made?

Comment: @Abigail your welcome. simply call printHour("val you want") at the end of script tag. check out my update..